# How to print results from for loop in one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below code is for loop to print many lists

```
for file in dir:

     res = p.Probability(base + i + "/" + file)
     print(i + ": " + ": " + str(res))
     print(res)
    #docum = []
    #docum.append(res)
print(docum)
```

for loop result will be:

```
[['hello',123]['hi',456]]
[['hello',123]['hi',456]]
[['hello',123]['hi',456]]
[['hello',123]['hi',456]]
[['hello',123]['hi',456]]
```

but I want to print as a one list

```
[['hello',123]['hi',456],['hello',123]['hi',456],['hello',123]['hi',456]]
```

how can I do that. I tried many things but still not working. I am new to python. and one more help how to separate hi and hello.
like:

```
        hi       hello
        456      123
        456      123
        456      123
```

I am doing school project for my class 11th. I struck in this and I am new to coding

Comment: please ignore this line. print(i + ": " + ": " + str(res))

Comment: Your 'result' and your expected output both are missing several commas. It is also not clear what exactly you are expecting, a single list or a table being printed out.

Comment: And you can [edit] your question rather than ask us to ignore a line. Post what *should be part of your question* and no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docum = []
for file in dir:

 res = p.Probability(base + i + "/" + file)
 print(i + ": " + ": " + str(res))
 print(res)

docum.append(res)
print(docum)
```

initialize the first list outside of the for loop, so it you're not constantly creating a new one and override the old entries.

About your second question about how to separate hi and hello:

You could run a for loop and check every first element of the array with a condition ( if res[i][0] = 'hi'), assuming you wanted the list the way you described

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: second question. I can't get the proper out put for second question.

Comment: any suggestions?